# Populate array with multiples of 25 up to certain limit - JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm trying to create an array that will include numbers of 25 up to 300.
For example:

```
const arr = [25, 50, 75, 100, 125...., 300];
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
var every25to300 = 300; 

for (var i = 0; i <= every25to300; i++) {
   console.log(i);
}
```

I've tried something like `console.log(i + 25)` but that starts from 25 and goes up to 325.
I know I'm doing something wrong just not sure what exactly. Can I ask for some help, please?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could use a generator, can even make the generator configurable.

```js
function* incGenerator(start = 0, inc = 25, limit = 300) {
  let i = start;
  while (i < limit) {
    i += inc;
    yield i;
  }
  return limit;
}

const arr = [...incGenerator()];
const arr2 = [...incGenerator(50, 100, 500)];

console.log(arr);
console.log(arr2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array#from` to generate your array.

```js
const arr = Array.from({length: 12}, (_,i) => (i+1) * 25)
console.log(arr);
```

You can increment in steps of 25.

```js
const every25to300 = 300, result = [];
for (let i = 25; i <= every25to300; i += 25) {
   result.push(i);
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to multiply `i` by `25` inside the loop and divide the upper limit by `25`:

```js
var every25to300 = 300; 

for (var i = 0; i <= every25to300 / 25; i++) {
   console.log(i * 25);
}
```

Or alternatively, increment `i` by `25` on every iteration:

```js
var every25to300 = 300;

for (var i = 0; i <= every25to300; i += 25) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

---

To construct an array, use the [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method:

```js
const arr = [];
var every25to300 = 300;

for (var i = 0; i <= every25to300; i += 25) {
  arr.push(i);
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution, You can use step 25(i=i+25) to increment instead of i++

```js
const step = 25;
const initial = 25;
const every25to300 = 300;
let result = [];
for (let i = 25; i <= every25to300; i = i + 25) {
  result.push(i);
}

console.log(result);

// using while loop
result = [];
let index = 0;
while (index < every25to300) {
  index = index + 25;
  result.push(index);
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get loop time value then push it

```
var start = 25; 
var end = 300
var arry = [];

for(var i = 1; i<= end/start; i++){
   arry.push( i * start )
}

 console.log(arry)
```